# using mobiscroll datepicker in require js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mobiscroll

I have a backbone jquery mobile app in which i want to use mobiscroll date picker.
I tried include it in the `head` tag.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'widget' of undefined
```

But i am getting this error.

Is mobiscroll require js compatible ?
How can i load it to use it within my views directly ?

Comment: can you show us related codes as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're including Mobi Pick's JS file **after** Jquery Mobile.

I'm new to jQuery Mobile and realized I did that mistake just now. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just include mobiscroll the same way you include jquery and set the dependency on jquery. I'm posting here an example how you can include mobiscroll with require.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min'
      mobiscroll: 'vendor/mobiscroll/mobiscroll..min'
    },
    shim: {
       jquery:{
          exports: "jquery"
       },
       mobiscroll:{
          deps: ['jquery'],
          exports: "mobiscroll"
       }
    }
});
require(['domReady','app', 'mobiscroll'],
   function(domReady, App){
   ...
});
```